# AngularJs: how to send data to an HTML popup and list it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Experienced people

I am unable to send the information to my html below is the file abcController.js:

$scope.openSituationWorkflow = function () {

```
   var id = $scope.data.id ;
   var EventWorkflow = ["$scope", "$modalInstance", "TableFactory", "ConsultFactory", function ($scope, $modalInstance, TableFactory, ConsultFactory) {
      $rootScope.isPopup = true;
      $scope.innerTemplate = contextPath+"xyz/view/consultLocalWorkflow.html";
      ConsultFactory.openWorkflowRest(id).then(function(data) {         
      });

      $scope.popupTable = new TableFactory (
         {
            service: ConsultFactory.openSituationWorkflowRest(id),
            remotePagination: false
         });

      $scope.filtro = {field: "id", value: id};

      $scope.close = function () {
         $modalInstance.close();
      };
   }];

   modalService.open({windowClass: "clmListaPopup", controller: EventWorkflow });
};
```

here is my popup with a table (consultLocalWorkflow.html)

```
<div class="content" style="background-color: white; padding: 20px;">
    <table adsm-table="popupTable"
           data-adsm-table-internal-loading="true"
           class="table adsm-table-hover table-condensed adsm-table"
           style="width: 100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in page ">
            <td column-title="aprovador" style="min-width: 140px; max-width: 400px;">{{ row.integrante }}</td>
            <td column-title="dataLiberacao" align="center" >{{ row.dhLiberacao | dateTimeZone}}</td>
            <td column-title="dataAcao" align="center" >{{ row.dhAcao | dateTimeZone }}</td>
            <td column-title="situacao" >{{ row.tpSituacaoAcao }}</td>
            <td column-title="observacao" >{{ row.obAcao }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="btnClose" class="fix-btn" data-ng-click="close()" data-ng-bind="'fechar' | translate"></button>
</div>
```

The popup opens but the data is not listed on the screen. What am I wrong?

Comment: You should use the `javascript` instead of the `java` tag. Please edit your question.

Comment: Although your comment didn't add anything, I changed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the page array you listed in HTML whether it exists in JS file. It seems that you didn't set up the 'page' property in JS file.